# How to calculate a mod b in Python?

Tags: python

Is there a modulo function in the Python `math` library?

Isn't `15 % 4`, 3? But `15 mod 4` is 1, right?

Comment: 3 equals 15 mod 4.

Comment: You're probably thinking that (15 mod 4 = -1) which is the same as saying (15 mod 4 = 3)

Comment: Beware: (-41) % 3 == -2 in C, but (-41) % 3 == 1 in Python  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/828092/python-style-integer-division-modulus-in-c

Answer (score 263, accepted):

There's the `%` sign.  It's not just for the remainder, it is the modulo operation.

Answer (score 60):

you can also try [`divmod(x, y)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#divmod) which returns a tuple `(x // y, x % y)`

Answer (score 43):

```
>>> 15 % 4
3
>>>
```

The modulo gives the remainder after integer division.

Answer (score 28):

`mod = a % b`

This stores the result of `a mod b` in the variable `mod`.

And you are right, `15 mod 4` is 3, which is exactly what python returns:

```
>>> 15 % 4
3
```

`a %= b` is also valid.

Answer (score 11):

Why don't you use % ?

```
print 4 % 2 # 0
```

Answer (score 5):

I don't think you're fully grasping modulo. `a % b` and `a mod b` are just two different ways to express modulo. In this case, python uses `%`. No, `15 mod 4` is not `1`, `15 % 4 == 15 mod 4 == 3`.

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [3, 1, 2, 4]
for a in A:
    print(a % 2)
```

output:

```
1
1
0
0
```