# How to convert a modular arithmetic equation to python code?

Tags: python, modular-arithmetic

```
(x/y) mod n = ((x mod n) * (y mod n)^-1) mod n
```

I would like to know how to convert the above statement into python.

Comment: What specific part of that do you already know how to do? What part _don't_ you know how to do? Do you know how to do a modulo at all, in general? What research have you done? How close have you gotten to a correct solution?

Comment: Also, build a title to be talking about _the problem_, not about _you_. The goal is that the question and its answers should be helpful to everyone with the same issue, so other people trying to figure out how to do the same specific thing should be able to find it and learn from its answers.

Comment: ...as an example of a preexisting question that covers a lot of the same space, see [How to calculate a mod b in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/991027/how-to-calculate-a-mod-b-in-python) -- to prevent this question from being duplicate, it would help to show where you get stuck when trying to apply that preexisting question's answers.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this,

consider,

```
x=10
y=5
n=2
# You can use if condition to evaluate the expression
if (x/y)%n==((x%n)*(y%n)**(-1)):
    print('Condition satisfied')
else:
    print('Condition not satisfied')
```

Comment: I don't think that's what they mean, but it's a clever interpretation. Forgot the last %n, though.