# How to loop some amount of number in python

Tags: python

I want to make the number begin from zero if it is more than twenty-five. For example,
x = 24 + 10 must be 8. How can I do that?

Comment: You mean `(24 + 10) % 26` ?

Comment: Please provide a minimum reproducible example and show what you've tried so far. 

https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Also, I would assume you are looking for something as simple as `24+10-25` but that would be 9.

Comment: @talfreds They want it to start at 0 when it's 26, not 25.

Comment: Right;.  Go look up the "modulo" concept.

Comment: @khelwood This question is Python, not Java.

Comment: [How to calculate a mod b in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/991027/3890632)

Comment: Or [Find the division remainder of a number](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5584586/3890632)

Comment: @barmar You're right, that's what OP means. My logic for -25 is that if it starts at 0 after 25, subtracting 26 would be starting at 1 after 25

Comment: I want it like whenever you plus  some amount of number, it has to be no more than 25, it should begin from zero when it reaches 25. when it is 26, it must be equal to 0

Comment: Yes, exactly. But the number 26 must be equal to 0 and the number of 27 must be equal to 1 etc. But if I add bigger numbers, for example, 24 + 5, the result must be 3. But if I use that if statement you wrote, it makes it equal to 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use the modulus operator, or `%`. `a % b` finds the remainder when you divide a by b. If you want to keep the number at 25 or lower, you should take the mod with 26.

```
def add_and_wrap(n1, n2, wrap_at):
    return (n1 + n2) % (wrap_at + 1)
```

Comment: the question is a bit too unclear to write an answer already