# Using the mod operator correctly in C

Tags: c, hash, hashtable

In a hash table implementation in C, I am relying on the mod operator to transform my hash of the key by the capacity of the hash table as follows:

```
int i = compute_index(key, hash, capacity);

while(table[i].occupied && (strcmp(table[i].key, key) != 0))
{
    ...
```

The hash seems to be computed correctly, because in my debugger, I am able to utilize the hash function and the key to output -724412585.

[image]

The strange thing is, when I mod this number by the capacity using a regular calculator, I get 7. But within the debugger, and my code, the integer -1 is returned. This is very confusing and I would appreciate some help.

My compute_index() simply does this:

```
int compute_index(const char* key, int (*hash)(const char*), int cap)
{
    return hash(key) % cap;
}
```

Would appreciate some guidance, thank you.

Comment: Usually you would want a hash to be an unsigned int. Or even an unsigned long, since int might not be very wide.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4003232/how-to-code-a-modulo-operator-in-c-c-obj-c-that-handles-negative-numbers, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24074869/why-is-the-behavior-of-the-modulo-operator-different-between-c-and-ruby-for, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/828092/python-style-integer-division-modulus-in-c

Comment: The correct type to use for the hash function is `size_t` and nothing else, since this type will most likely be used as look-up index in an array.

Answer (score 1):

There are two common conventions for the sign of `a % b`: in one case, the sign is the same as `b` (i.e. always positive when `b` is positive), and in the other case it's the same as `a` (i.e. negative when `a` is negative). Older versions of C allowed either behavior, but C99 and later require the second behavior (which goes hand-in-hand with requiring truncating division, rather than leaving the choice of truncating or flooring division up to the compiler).

The upshot of this is that if your `hash` function can return a negative number, then `hash(key) % cap` will also be negative sometimes. The simplest thing you can do is to alter `hash` to return `unsigned int` instead of `int`.

Comment: @M.M sorry, massive thinko when I was writing that. Corrected :)

Comment: In case this is the reason for the error, then the question is a duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division).

Answer (score 0):

I agree w/ everything @hobbs said, except for the following:

I believe the easiest thing you can do is either:

- change the output of `hash()` to `unsigned int`,
- or cast the output of `hash()` to `unsigned int` within the body of `compute_index()` before the modulo operation, or
- add the modulus back in if the result of the `%` operation < 0 (to get the abstract-algebraic sense of "integer mod q").

The behavior of `%` in C for negative numbers can be confusing to those with a background in abstract algebra, particularly for one who works with the rings of integers mod q.