# Can integer division in C/C++ run into loss of precision issues?

Tags: c++, c

Suppose we have three integer (int, long, long long, unsigned int, etc) variables `a, b, c`. Normally, performing

```
c = a / b;
```

would result in truncate of fractions. However, is it possible for c to end up with an incorrect value?

I am not talking about a / b may be out of range for `c's type.` Rather, I am talking about how integer division is implemented in C. Does performing `a / b` first generate a float type intermediate result, and then the intermediate value is truncated?

If so, I wonder if loss of precision of the intermediate value can lead to an incorrect value of c. For example, suppose the precise value for a / b is 2, but somehow the intermediate result is `1.9999...`, thus c will end up with an incorrect value of 1. Can such cases happen, or does integer division always result in a correct value if the expected value is in the range of c's type?

Comment: This isn't Commodore basic, integer operations are done as integers. Integer arithmetic is generally more efficient than floating-point.

Comment: Integer math is done strictly with integers.  In fact some processors could only do floating point math and had an attached floating point math co-processor do deal with floating point numbers.

Comment: @NathanOliver So can I safely assume that integer division will always lead to a correct result?

Comment: You have to worry about overflow and underflow, but other than that, integer math is precise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Integer division rounding with negatives in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/319880/integer-division-rounding-with-negatives-in-c)

Comment: Yep.  You're guaranteed to get the same results.

Comment: @NathanOliver: There is no requirement from the C standard that integer operations be implemented with only integer arithmetic, just that the results be correct. An implementation could use floating-point hardware to implement integer operations as long as it gets the results right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Does performing a / b first generate a float type intermediate result

As far as the language is concerned, there are no intermediate results.

> does integer division always result in a correct value if the expected value is in the range of c's type?

Yes.

Comment: "There are no fractions in integer division", well, I think any reasonable binary division algorithm used on silicon will also produce the fraction (or remainder, which is essentially same thing as producing fractional part), and the "basic" division instruction on a CPU will also give the remainder as part of the result (SIMD instructions probably discard it).

Comment: @hyde There is not always a need to generate a fraction (or use some `idiv` equivalent): https://godbolt.org/z/aRaDWM - https://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/~jones/bcd/divide.html

Comment: @hyde Fraction is different from remainder, even if they're related concepts. Regardless, my answer is about the language. Hardware may do whatever it wants underneath, and the language implementation has to deal with it.

Comment: Yeah, of course there are special cases and optimizations for any operation where you have constants (depending on a CPU, probably for any compile time constant divisor). I'm not sure if it's fair to call that general "integer division" in this context.

Comment: Reminder is directly the numerator part of the fractions, with a known fixed denominator (at least for positive results, CBA to think it through for negative), so it is very nearly the same thing. Anyway, I believe current C++ standard at least does use fractions to define the result of integer division, so the concept of fractions exist for C++ integer division (can't discard something which does not exist).

Comment: From a recent draft found with google: *"For integral operands the / operator yields the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded;"*

Comment: @hyde oh, so it apparently does. Not the wording I would have chosen; not that it matters much either way. I removed the statement from the answer.

Comment: Yeah, this is just nitpicking and semantics... I just got bothered by the absolute tone of the original first point.

Answer (score 3):

Section 6.5.5 of the C11 standards states

> When integers are divided, the result of the `/` operator is the algebraic quotient with any fractional  part  discarded. **If  the  quotient `a/b` is representable,  the  expression `(a/b)*b  +  a%b` shall equal `a;`**

Which means there's no way, mathematically, that you'll get wrong results.

Comment: That's not actually what that says. :)

Comment: @RobertHarvey well, if the result was imprecise like OP asks, supposing no remainder, `(a / b) * b` would never result in `a` (since `1.99999...` is not representable, thus not being exact). Same thing if there was a reminder. Or maybe I'm just reading too much into this.

Comment: All it means is that an incorrect result must be reversible ;)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit ok, but "incorrect" in this case would mean "imprecise". The question was originally about loss of precision. If that was the case, wouldn't the result of `(a/b) * b` be different from `a`? I'm sure I'm missing something when two other users are telling me I'm misinterpreting this, but I can't seem to see it.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca The question is about incorrectness resulting from imprecise intermediate stages (which don't exist). All you've proven is that, if said imprecision existed, it would be symmetrical, which doesn't prove that the result in one direction is "correct" mathematically. It will be, but this quote isn't why.

Comment: The not-bolded part is the part which says that there cannot be any loss of precision.

Answer (score 2):

> Suppose we have three integer (int, long, long long, unsigned int, etc) variables a, b, c. Normally, performing
>
> ```
> c = a / b;
> ```
>
> would result in truncate of fractions. However, is it possible for `c` to end up with an incorrect value? *I am not talking about a / b may be out of range for c's type.*

It should not be possible that for example the last digit of division be *wrong*, if all rules were followed otherwise. [C11 6.5.5p6](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.5p6):

> When integers are divided, the result of the **`/`** operator **is the algebraic quotient with any fractional part discarded.**

i.e. the result is not "close" to but exactly the same as a / b would be algebraically, just anything following the point discarded.

That does not mean there won't be any gotchas: it is possible that the division of `a / b` might be mathematically not out of range for `c`'s type yet out of range for the type used in the division itself which can cause wrong values be set in c.

Consider this example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>   

int main(void) {
    int32_t a = INT32_MIN;
    int32_t b = -1;
    int64_t c = a / b;
    printf("%" PRId64, c);
}
```

The result of division of `INT32_MIN / -1` is representable in `c`, it is `INT32_MAX + 1`, which is **positive**. However on 32-bit platforms the arithmetic happens in 32 bits, and this division produces an integer overflow which causes the behaviour to be undefined. What happens on my computer is that if I compile without optimizations it **aborts** the program. If I compile with optimizations enabled (`-O3`), the compiler will resolve this calculation at compilation time, and handles the overflow in a peculiar way and produces the result `-2147483648` which is *negative*.

Likewise, if you do this:

```
uint16_t a = 16;
int16_t b = -1;
int32_t result = a / b;
printf("%" PRId32 "\n", result);
```

the result on a 32-bit int machine is -16. If you change the type of `a` to `uint32_t` the math happens in unsigned:

```
uint32_t a = 16;
int16_t b = -1;
int32_t result = a / b;
printf("%" PRId32 "\n", result);
```

The result is **of course `0`**. And you would get `0` from the **former calculation too** on a 16-bit machine.